# Select Top N Per Group using Flink Sql

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using Flink SQL to handle batch case.
How can I get the top-n record per group using FLINK SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink SQL (until version 1.7) does not provide a [built-in aggregation function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/functions.html#aggregate-functions) for top-n.

You can implement a [user-defined aggregation function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/udfs.html#aggregation-functions) to support you use case.